# Read content of file which is in GitHub using PyGitHub

Tags: python, github, readfile, pygithub

Let’s say "sample.txt" file is in GitHub under the "Demo" repository [Demo/sample.txt]. How can I read the content of *sample.txt* using [PyGitHub](https://pypi.org/project/PyGithub/) instead fetching from the API?

Else, do we have some other package to read such file content?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use this code to see the content of the file:

```
from github import Github
github = Github('user', 'password')
user = github.get_user()
repository = user.get_repo('Demo')
file_content = repository.get_contents('sample.txt')
print(file_content.decoded_content.decode())
```

If you need to see more attributes like *decoded_content*, just type this:

```
print(help(file_content))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`get_contents`](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Repository.html#github.Repository.Repository.get_contents) API

Here is an example:

```
from github import Github

github = Github('user', 'password')
user = github.get_user()
repository = user.get_repo('Demo')

file_content = repository.get_contents('sample.txt')
```